# Async Pipe failing when linked to newly created observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

When attaching an Async Pipe to a newly created Observable, you get the error

```
"Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"
```

Here is a Plunkr demonstrating what I'm talking about:
https://plnkr.co/edit/vljXImCYoNubjyxOaWo3?p=preview

However, if I comment out

```
private asyncList: Observable<string[]> = new Observable<string[]>();
```

and un-comment

```
//private asyncList: Observable<string[]>;
```

then the page will load without a problem.  Maybe I'm missing something blatantly obvious but this is throwing me for a loop.

This Plunkr was forked from someone else's and I did the least amount of work to demo the error, so please excuse any weird naming or practices you see.

Comment: You don't create an observable by doing `new Observable<T>()`. You could do something like `Observable.create((o) => {})`. But I imagine you probably want a subject instead so you can emit values on it. Not clear on your usage.

Comment: Edit:  It looks like doing new Observable just calls Observable.create() as mentioned by @martin so it seems like it's not necessarily bad practice to do.

Comment: Oh, cool. I couldn't find any documentation on newing it up and hadn't seen anyone do it before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `new Observable()` is the same as calling `Observable.create()` which means you need to supply it with a "subscription" function that emits values to the observer on subscription. For example:

```
private asyncList = new Observable<string[]>(o => o.next('Hello'));
```

Notice that the error in your demo thrown in the Observable and not in the pipe itself.

I'm actually surprised that the [parameter in the Observable class is optional](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L42). I'm not aware of any use-case where you might ignore it...

Comment: I didn't know that `new Observable()` is the same as calling `Observable.create()`, that makes a lot of sense.  The curious thing to me is that if I just leave the property as `private asyncList: Observable<string[]>;` then it doesn't throw a fit at all?  Wouldn't `asyncList` be undefined in that case?

Comment: Additionally, why doesn't just doing a `new Observable()` then subscribing to it later throw an error?

Comment: `null` is a valid value (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.3/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L90) because you might just want to unsubscribe from the previous Observable and do nothing. That's why `null` doesn't throw anything. The error is thrown from around here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L201 so it's just not an expected state (what would do this Observable anyway?).

Comment: Ah so I think I understand it a little better now; I thought you could create an observable with no subscription and still subscribe to it later but that actually throws the exact same error.  I was using the observable as an `@Input()` property for a component but I didn't want to have to check if it's defined or not before using it so I gave it an initial value but it looks like the template binding will happen before that value from the parent is retrieved so it throws an error.  I see now.  Thank you.